# Thread is not wake up at notify_all

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

I don't understand something,i'm making a multithreading programming which is itself really simple, it does some operation on a given vector.

If i execute my main which is this :

```
Workers workers(4);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));


for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
  workers.printThread(-1,"[ Asking for initialization ]");
  std::vector<int> vector;
  workers.initialize(vector,100);
  workers.waitResult();
  displayArray(vector);

  workers.printThread(-1,"[ Asking for maximum ]");
  workers.maximum(vector);
  workers.waitResult();
  std::cout << "Maximum = " << workers.getResult() << std::endl;

  workers.printThread(-1,"[ Asking for number of occurences ]");
  workers.nbOccurences(vector,10);
  workers.waitResult();
  std::cout << "Number of occurence for ' " << 10 << " ' = " << workers.getResult() << std::endl;

  workers.printThread(-1,"[ Asking for first occurence ]");
  workers.firstOccurence(vector,10);
  workers.waitResult();
  std::cout << "First occurence for ' " << 10 << " ' = " << workers.getResult() << std::endl;
}
return 0;
```

If my loop iteration condition is not a huge number (only 1,5,10.. turn in the loop, there is not problem, but when i execute this several type, i get an error because one of my thread is not wake up.. To be more clear, here is my code which i suspect to be the problem:

```
void Workers::threadsRoutine(int i)
{
    printThread(i,"Co-Routine");
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cvMutex);
    cv.wait(lk,[this,i]{printThread2(i,currentOrder != Order::NONE); return currentOrder != Order::NONE;});

    printThread(i,"is wake up");
    lk.unlock();

    printThread(i,"Gonna execute order");
    switch(currentOrder){
    case Order::INITIALIZE:
        printThread(i,"gonna initialize");
        initializeThreaded(i,*pointer);
        printThread(i,"initialize done");
        break;
    case Order::MAXIMUM:
        printThread(i,"gonna compute maximum");
        maximumThreaded(i,*pointer);
        printThread(i,"maximum computed");
        break;
    case Order::NB_OCCURENCE:
        printThread(i,"gonna compute number of occurences");
        nbOccurencesThreaded(i,*pointer);
        printThread(i,"number of occurences computed");
        break;
    case Order::FIRST_OCCURENCE:
        printThread(i,"gonna compute first occurence");
        firstOccurenceThreaded(i,*pointer);
        printThread(i,"first occurence computed");
        break;
    case Order::STOP:
        if(barrier->wait()){
            currentOrder = Order::NONE;
            endResult = true;
            cvWaitResult.notify_one();
        }
        return;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    if(barrier->wait()){
        currentOrder = Order::NONE;
        endResult = true;
        cvWaitResult.notify_one();
    }
    threadsRoutine(i);
}
```

Here is one of mine calling method which call notify_all

```
void maximum(std::vector<int>& path) 
{
    results = INT_MIN;
    endResult = false;
    currentOrder = Order::MAXIMUM;
    cv.notify_all();
}
```

So basically, i have print a lot of things and here's the output :

```
{ Thread N° 1 boolean value : 1 }
{ Thread N° 1 : is wake up }
{ Thread N° 1 : Gonna execute order }
{ Thread N° 1 : gonna compute number of occurences }
{ Thread N° 1 : number of occurences computed }
TMP nb threads = 1
{ Thread N° 0 : Co-Routine }
{ Thread N° 0 boolean value : 0 }
{ Thread N° -1 : [ Asking for first occurence ] }
{ Thread N° 2 : Co-Routine }
{ Thread N° 1 : Co-Routine }
{ Thread N° 2 boolean value : 0 }
{ Thread N° 3 : Co-Routine }
{ Thread N° 1 boolean value : 0 }
{ Thread N° -1 : FIRST }
{ Thread N° -1 : NOTIFY }
{ Thread N° 3 boolean value : 1 }
{ Thread N° 3 : is wake up }
{ Thread N° 3 : Gonna execute order }
{ Thread N° 3 : gonna compute first occurence }
{ Thread N° 3 : first occurence computed }
TMP nb threads = 4
{ Thread N° 0 boolean value : 1 }
{ Thread N° 0 : is wake up }
{ Thread N° 0 : Gonna execute order }
{ Thread N° 0 : gonna compute first occurence }
{ Thread N° 0 : first occurence computed }
TMP nb threads = 3
{ Thread N° 2 boolean value : 1 }
{ Thread N° 2 : is wake up }
{ Thread N° 2 : Gonna execute order }
{ Thread N° 2 : gonna compute first occurence }
{ Thread N° 2 : first occurence computed }
TMP nb threads = 2
```

It really start at asking first occurence but above that, it's the previous operation.

So as you can see, my Thread N°1 in this case is never wake up because there is not message according to it...

Sorry if my explaination are bad, ask me if it is the case and i'll try to reformate.

Thanks

Comment: `threadsRoutine` is recursive on all paths.

Comment: I cannot find where you call `notify_all`

Comment: Not it is not no-terminate recursive on STOP path because the thread just return or maybe i didn't understand ? OH yeah sorry i totally forgot the calling notify_all method, i edit my post !

Comment: Too much. Post a [MCVE], all in one piece that we can cut/paste/compile/run. Chances are pretty good that you will find a mistake or two while you are doing so.

Comment: Just scanning a few lines, I see that `unique_lock` and `cv.wait` are used improperly. Work on that [MCVE].

Comment: Note that you **must** hold the lock when changing the condition you want to signal about. Otherwise there is a data race.

Comment: You should lock cvMutex  when you modify `currentOrder` (and unlock it before you call `notify_all`)